# Distributing app with .so files?

Tags: libraries, c, shared-library

I'm trying to make a game in C with SDL and OpenGL. **Q:** Will my game run on computers without SDL installed if I ship the .so files in my game folder?

I mean adding the .so files somewhere in the game folder and linking against them in the same way windows' apps do it with .dll files, so people won't need to install the libraries in order to run my game.

Comment: Yep! Just look at (Linux) [Dwarf Fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) for an example! Just make sure that it looks for the libraries INSIDE the install.

Comment: could you repeat that as an answer so I can check the question as answered?

Comment: Sure! One second!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A:** Yes! Make sure that you look for the libraries inside your install, rather than the system's default area for libraries. 
The best example I can think to give of this is [Dwarf Fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/df_40_24_linux.tar.bz2)'s tar ball.